# android classnotfoundexception didn't find class on path dexpathlist

Tags: java, android

I've been working on an android project and i've been trying to solve this exception for a while, I tried many things but nothing works, do you have any idea what might be causing it ?

```
01-17 16:09:50.705: E/AndroidRuntime(1167): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-17 16:09:50.705: E/AndroidRuntime(1167): Process: com.ja.helloup, PID:1167
01-17 16:09:50.705: E/AndroidRuntime(1167): java.lang.RuntimeException:Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.ja.helloup/com.ja.helloup.HelloUpActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.ja.helloup.HelloUpActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.ja.helloup-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.ja.helloup-2, /system/lib]]
01-17 16:09:50.705: E/AndroidRuntime(1167):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2121)
01-17 16:09:50.705: E/AndroidRuntime(1167):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
01-17 16:09:50.705: E/AndroidRuntime(1167):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
01-17 16:09:50.705: E/AndroidRuntime(1167):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
01-17 16:09:50.705: E/AndroidRuntime(1167):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-17 16:09:50.705: E/AndroidRuntime(1167):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
01-17 16:09:50.705: E/AndroidRuntime(1167):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
01-17 16:09:50.705: E/AndroidRuntime(1167):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-17 16:09:50.705: E/AndroidRuntime(1167):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-17 16:09:50.705: E/AndroidRuntime(1167):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
01-17 16:09:50.705: E/AndroidRuntime(1167):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
01-17 16:09:50.705: E/AndroidRuntime(1167):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-17 16:09:50.705: E/AndroidRuntime(1167): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.ja.helloup.HelloUpActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.ja.helloup-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.ja.helloup-2, /system/lib]]
01-17 16:09:50.705: E/AndroidRuntime(1167):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
01-17 16:09:50.705: E/AndroidRuntime(1167):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
01-17 16:09:50.705: E/AndroidRuntime(1167):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
01-17 16:09:50.705: E/AndroidRuntime(1167):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
01-17 16:09:50.705: E/AndroidRuntime(1167):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2112)
```

and here is my android manifest file

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.ja.helloup">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
   <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ja_appicon"
    android:label="@string/app_name">

    <activity
        android:name=".HelloUpActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name=".HelloUpActivity" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
   </application>
   </manifest>
```

my package explorer looks  like this:

```
HelloUPActivity
 +src<emptyfoulder>
 +gen
 +assests
 +bin
 +java
   +com
     +ja
       +helloup
         HelloUpActivity.java
 +res
 manifest
```

Comment: you've probably tried this already, but have you tried cleaning your project?

Comment: @patrickdamery   yes i did

Answer (score 0):

Single filter required:-

```
    <activity

    android:name=".HelloUpActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: I used a single filter but the exception is still thrown

Answer (score 0):

The name of the action in the second intent filter looks incorrect, check the official documentation for [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html).

Comment: I changed the name of the intent filter but the problem is still there

Comment: are you sure your `HelloUpActivity` is in package `com.ja.helloup`?

Comment: I tried to add an image of my package explorer but i couldn't because of my low reputation points, so i edited the question to explain my project hierarchy

Comment: why your src folder is empty! you should something like src->main and inside main folder there is java and res. Try create a new empty project with a blank activity with androidstudio wizard.